# using boto3 in a python3 virtual env in AWS Lambda

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.4, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to use **Python3.4** and **boto3** to walk an **S3** bucket and publish some file locations to an **RDS** instance.  The part of this effort I am having trouble with is when using boto3.  My lambda function looks like the following:

```
import subprocess

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    args = ("venv/bin/python3.4", "run.py")
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    popen.wait()
    output = popen.stdout.read()
    print(output)
```

and, in my **run.py** file I have some lines:

```
import boto3

s3c = boto3.client('s3')
```

which cause an exception.  The **run.py** file is not relevant for this question however, so in order make this post more concise, I've found that the cause of this error is generated with executing the lambda function:

```
import subprocess

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    args = ("python3.4", "-c", "import boto3; print(boto3.client('s3'))")
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    popen.wait()
    output = popen.stdout.read()
    print(output)
```

My logstream reports the error:

```
Event Data
START RequestId: 2b65421a-664d-11e6-81db-974c7c09d283 Version: $LATEST 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
 File "/var/runtime/boto3/__init__.py", line 79, in client 
 return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs) 
 File "/var/runtime/boto3/session.py", line 250, in client 
 aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config) 
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/session.py", line 818, in create_client 
 client_config=config, api_version=api_version) 
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 63, in create_client 
 cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model) 
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 85, in _create_client_class 
 base_classes=bases) 
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit 
 return self._emit(event_name, kwargs) 
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit 
 response = handler(**kwargs) 
 File "/var/runtime/boto3/utils.py", line 61, in _handler 
 module = import_module(module) 
 File "/var/runtime/boto3/utils.py", line 52, in import_module 
 __import__(name) 
 File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 13, in <module> 
 from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer 
 File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 135, in <module> 
 from concurrent import futures 
 File "/var/runtime/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module> 
 from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED, 
 File "/var/runtime/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357 
 raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback 
 ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
END RequestId: 2b65421a-664d-11e6-81db-974c7c09d283 
REPORT RequestId: 2b65421a-664d-11e6-81db-974c7c09d283  Duration: 2673.45 ms    Billed Duration: 2700 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB   Max Memory Used: 61 MB
```

I need to use boto3 downstream of run.py.  Any ideas on how to resolve this are much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What does your deployment package look like?

Comment: I've got a zip uploaded to (and imported from) S3.  This zip contains the virtualenv, a lambda file, and another file, called run.py, in which the s3 boto3 client is created.  run.py is launched with venv/bin/python3.4.  boto3 is installed in the venv, but AWS Lambda presumably creates a PYTHONPATH env var which lists /var/runtime first.  even when sys.path is hacked, boto3 is sought in venv, but modules boto3 depends on are sought in /var/runtime.  please note this sys.path reordering was just an exploratory effort, not a solution.  hopefully this lends more environment context.

Comment: Did you include `concurrent.futures` in your venv?

Comment: I did not.  How/where is concurrent.futures used?  Thanks!

Comment: Try to reduce this to a minimum working example. What happens if you run: 
`import boto3` `def lambda_handler(event, context):` `return('OK')`

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: post the simplest *run.py* that you tried here. I think it's relevant

Comment: Why you cannot use python 3.4 in AWS Lambda directly?